# How to add calculated fields to SQL list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am tracking fuel for trucks.

```
        List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> data = new List<FuelLightTruckDataSource>();

        using (SystemContext ctx = new SystemContext())
        {

            List<FuelLightTruckDataSource> dataTransfers
                = ctx.FuelTransfer
                    .Where(tr => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tr.Date) >= from.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(tr.Date) <= to.Date
                        //&& tr.ToAsset.AssignedToEmployee.Manager
                        && tr.ToAsset.AssignedToEmployee != null
                        && tr.ToAsset.AssetType.Code == "L"
                        && tr.Volume != null)
                        //&& (tr.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "GAS" || tr.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass.Code == "DSL"))
                    .GroupBy(tr => new { tr.ToAsset, tr.Date, tr.FuelTankLog.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass, tr.FuelTankLog.FuelCard.FuelVendor,tr.Volume, tr.ToAssetOdometer })
                    .Select(g => new FuelLightTruckDataSource()
                    {
                        Asset = g.FirstOrDefault().ToAsset,
                        Employee = g.FirstOrDefault().ToAsset.AssignedToEmployee,
                        ProductClass = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelTankLog.FuelProductType.FuelProductClass,
                        Vendor = g.FirstOrDefault().FuelTankLog.FuelCard.FuelVendor,
                        FillSource = FuelFillSource.Transfer,
                        Source = "Slip Tank",
                        City = "",
                        Volume = g.FirstOrDefault().Volume.Value,
                        Distance = g.FirstOrDefault().ToAssetOdometer,
                        Date = g.FirstOrDefault().Date,
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

After my query, I need to calculate the consumption rate and distance traveled.  "Result" will be a collection of entries including "consumptionRate" and "Distance" and it matches the query above.

```
            // Get consumption rate data for each asset
            foreach (int assetId in assetIds)
            {
                FuelConsumptionRateQueryResult result = FuelConsumptionRateQueryService.Get(assetId, from, to, AssetCounterType.Odometer);
                result.Entries.ToList();
            }
```

My question is how do I get the result of my foreach loop and add them to my previous query/list, so they can show up in the report?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be due to the fact that you're declaring `result` as a new variable at each iteration of the `foreach` loop, causing `result` to be overwritten. Additionally, `result` isn't in scope once you finish with the `foreach` loop.

Instead, you probably want something closer to:

```
var allResults = new List<T>; //where T is whatever object type this is (FuelConsumptionRateQueryResult?)

foreach (int assetId in assetIds)
{ 
    //this is a new variable at each iteration of the loop
    FuelConsumptionRateQueryResult result = FuelConsumptionRateQueryService.Get(assetId, from, to, AssetCounterType.Odometer);
    allResults.Add(result); //add the current result to your list (outside the scope of this loop)
}
```

Basically, declare your variable outside of the loop and `Add` each individual result to the `allResults` list.

Comment: How do I add the allResults to my other List dataTransfer in the correct order? Basically, the allResults and dataTransfer will have the same number of entries but are grouped in a different way.

Comment: Furthermore, similar to having
                      Employee = .FirstOrDefault().ToAsset.AssignedToEmployee,
I would like to have 
ConsumptionRate = "some code that links to my allResults"

Comment: @RFS If you want to add it back to the list you're using, just do that instead of creating an `allResults` list. The issue with your current code is that you don't seem to be assigning the `FuelConsumptionRateQueryResult result` to anything.

Comment: You mentioned "just do that instead of creating `allResults`"? I am not sure I follow

Answer (score 0):

Create the additional data by a LINQ statement and concatenate both lists:

```
var results = assetIds.Select(id => FuelConsumptionRateQueryService
                           .Get(id, from, to, AssetCounterType.Odometer);
dataTransfers = dataTransfers.Concat(results);
```